# Hide Toolbar in userControlTextEditor DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a winforms application and I'm using DevExpress (v14.2) components, which include the `userControlTextEditor` (an text editor that can read, edit and save RTF format).

My problems is: this form should just be a viewer of the RTF that's in my database, that said, there is no reason to keep the toolbar from shortcuts/actions in the component. But I can't find where to set the `Visible` property (or something like that) to hide the toolbar.

[image: Screenshot]

I've been trying  `UserControlEditor.BarManager.MainMenu.Visible = false`  but the MainMenu is always null, so I just get the NullReference Exception.

Does anyone know how to hide/remove this toolbar from the userControlTextEditor component of DevExpress?

Comment: There are no classes like `userControlTextEditor` or `UserControlEditor` in DevExpress. If you want just only RTF editor without bars, so just create a new form, add `RichControl` to it and do not add bars.

Comment: Please show some code of you implementation so that somebody can understand to issue in your implementation. As @nempoBu4 said there are no such control and your question looks like tempo.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have not one bar, but several. To hide the all, traverse through the [BarManager.Bars](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarManager_Barstopic) collection and set Visible for all bars to False.

```
foreach(var bar in BarManager.Bars) {
    bar.Visible = false;
}
```